# macros and math mode

Tags: math-mode, macros

I am trying to create two new macros:

- `braces`: compiles some text between curly brackets
- `squakets`:  compiles text between two square brackets

I defined as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\braces}[2]{$\left\{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
    #1\\
    #2\\
    \end{tabular}\right\}$}    


\newcommand{\squakets}[1]{$\Big[ #1 \Big]$}

\begin{document}

\squakets{\squakets{\braces{$\sqrt{}$}{$\alpha$} \braces{$x$}{$\beta$}} \braces{$y$}{$\gamma$}} $\rightarrow$ \braces{$\sqrt{}$}{$\alpha$} -- \braces{$x$}{$\beta$} -- \braces{$y$}{$\gamma$}

\end{document}
```

Console still compiles, even though it warns me that:

> Missing $ inserted.

I was curious of understanding how to fix this. I guess it is something related to the fact I am embedding multiple `squakets` command in one another, but can someone help figure that out?

Comment: I'd call the second macro `squaces` ;o)

Comment: You are using the wrong approach here. What solves your problem is `\ensuremath{..}` rather than `$..$`. But still, if it's math, it should be in math mode, and not (*ab*)use `\ensuremath`.

Comment: You cannot nest `$...$`. You should either change them to `\ensuremath{}` or, preferably, remove them. Then use your macro inside math mode only.

Comment: Why not use `array` instead of tabular?

Comment: @Manuel And if it isn't maths ....

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mleftright}

\newcommand*\braces[2]{\mleft\{{\begingroup#1\endgroup\atop#2}\mright\}}
\newcommand*\squakets[1]{\Bigl[#1\Bigr]}

\begin{document}

\[
  \squakets{\squakets{\braces{\sqrt{}}{\alpha} \braces{x}{\beta}} \braces{y}{\gamma}}
  \to
  \braces{\sqrt{}}{\alpha} - \braces{x}{\beta} - \braces{y}{\gamma}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Manuel! However, your solution compiles something a bit different from what I had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all of your help!

This is the solution I came up with:

```
\newcommand*{\braces}[2]{\ensuremath{\left\{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
        #1\\
        #2\\
        \end{tabular}\right\}}}
```

As suggested in the comments above, `\ensuremath{}` instead of $...$ solves the issue.